# Online KML validator

Tags: web-apps, kml, gis

I wrote a [KML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language) file (geographic annotation XML) and want to validate it.

Is there a webapp for this?

Requirements:

- Free
- Able to validate big files like [this one (50,000 points)](https://github.com/wikivoyage/maps/blob/master/coordinates-but-no-image.kml?raw=true)

The webapps below all failed (sending feedback to their maintainers also failed):

- http://www.kmlvalidator.com
- http://feedvalidator.org